# Using Enums as Parameters in Openapi adds quotes to the parameter

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I am using Enums as parameter in api. But it results in the parameters being surrounded by quotes.

In the image below it shows how `%22` surrounds the parameter summary - `%22summary%22` as I select it from drop down.

How can I avoid adding quotes to the parameter ?

```
/v1/metrics/{profile}:
  parameters:
    - $ref: "#/components/parameters/profile"
  get:
    summary: Get list of field or summary profile metrics
    description: Retrieves list of metrics for field or summary profile
    tags:
      - profile-metrics
    responses:
      '200':
        description: OK
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/ProfileMetrics"
      '400':
        $ref: "#/components/responses/BadRequest"
      '404':
        $ref: "#/components/responses/NotFound"
      default:
        $ref: "#/components/responses/UnexpectedError"
```

profile parameter schema

```
profile:
  name: profile
  description: profile type either field or summary
  schema:
    type: string
    enum: [ field, summary ]
  in: path
  required: true
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in https://editor.swagger.io, the enum values appear without quotes there - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElSNa.png. What version of Swagger UI do you use? (Open the browser dev tools > Console tab > evaluate `versions`.) The latest version is 4.12.0, if yours is earlier then try the latest version. Do you use Swagger UI's standalone [`dist` assets](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist), or its npm module, or React component, or is your Swagger UI provided by some framework/library (e.g. as part of Swashbuckle or Springdoc)?

Comment: @Helen It shows up as - version: "3.26.2"

Comment: 4.12.0 works , checked now